# Bash script to open evince (pdf reader) and close terminal

Tags: bash, evince, kill

I'd like to write a script that, among other things, opens a PDF file with evince, and closes the terminal.

So far I've got:

```
evince &
sleep 2
kill -9 $PPID
```

but evince closes when the terminal does. I tried using `disown -h -a` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you want to have the script close the calling terminal? It makes some sense in the simplest case (see my comments on answers), but little in other cases. Also, just pressing `Ctrl-D` closes the terminal easily. Can you elaborate your use case? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using `nohup` you can avoid the evince process from being terminated with its parent process:

```
nohup evince &
sleep 2
kill -9 $PPID
```

more details on what nohup does and where it comes from can be found on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

> nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP
>   signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes
>   of logout.
>
> Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called
>   nohup.out if it has not already been redirected.

Comment: Looks like this may close the terminal if written in a script that is directly called from the first shell in the terminal. If there is one or more processes in between (for example, a script that calls another script), this will interrupt the closer parent, not close the terminal.

Comment: If this is really intended to be called in a script, the current answer does not allow to pass the PDF pathname(s) to evince. The `evince` line should be changed like this: `nohup evince "$@" &`

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu

```
nohup evince &
exit
```

works as desired. No sleep, no kill.

`kill -9` is overkill in any case, `kill -HUP` is perfectly good to kill a shell, and probably a terminal too... I don't want to check because with XFCE there seems to be only one terminal process for all the windows, so `kill -9 $PPID` would kill *all* my terminal windows.

Comment: this happens with gnome-terminal as well - so I would basically search for another option at all. if one writes this script in a bash-script-file, `exit` would only terminate the script itself, but not the terminal window. So I left `kill -9` in the script.

Comment: Can even write it in one line - `nohup evince & exit`

Comment: This answer looks like it would work when typed on the terminal, not when running a script from that terminal. By killing the parent PID (which, in a script, is the calling shell), @Philip's answer gets closer.